# Adding custom vertices to a Leftlet LineString / Polyline

Tags: leaflet, polygon, polyline, vertex, leaflet.draw

I have a normal Leaflet Draw page [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fullyboricua/taeeodow/), when I'm not in *editing mode* I would like to have custom vertex icon in some of the vertices that will also respond to click events, showing a popup.

I looked around and seems that I need to intercept the render of the line and draw my icon there.

**I'm not interested in adding markers**, I just want to add / tie an icon to the vertex, the same way Leaflet Draw does when you are in editing mode and shows white little rectangles.

Here's the idea of what I want to achieve, while out of editing mode. Something that looks like this (pardon my drawing skills!)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Cdv.png)

I think I can access the vertices with something like `myLine.geometry.features[0].coordinates`

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Where to I intercept the `render while not in editing` event? How do I tie and icon the the vertex?

Comment: Sorry, haven't got the time to give you a decent answer but for now this might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003140/leaflet-draw-polyline-vertices-only

Comment: @iH8 thanks! that other answer has some pointers for sure. The example does not show any rectangles (tried both in Chrome and IE) as you showed on the screenshot. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird. I'll have a stab at a new example tomorrow. That solution was buggy as hell anyway, have got a better solution.

Comment: @iH8 thanks, however since I'm using Leaftlet Draw I really don't see how I can apply your suggestions without getting inside the "guts" of the library

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I need to do the same thing, and possibly add a tooltip.